# Junit: How to test against multiple expected results from neo4j query?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, neo4j

My setup is Spring boot, Neo4J, Junit.
I am trying to test if there are two users sharing the same first name but different usernames (There are two in the database).
I am trying this:

```
    @Test
    public void findUsersByName(){
        Assert.assertEquals(FIRSTNAME1, userRepository.findUserByName(FIRSTNAME1).getName());
    }
```

which produces the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Result not of expected size. Expected 1 row but found 2
```

How can I test against multiple objects using jUnit? How would I declare that I expect two users both having the same FIRSTNAME1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that `userRepository.findUserByName()` finds two instances - not one - for the given `FIRSTNAME1` and it cannot abitrarily choose one over the other therefore it throws this exception. The exception is being thrown by `userRepository.findUserByName()`, it is **not** being thrown by JUnit.

You have a repository method which returns a single instance of user when queried by name, this implies that 'user name' is expected to be a unique value. However, you have two records in your store for the value of `FIRSTNAME1` which tells us that this expectation is not being enforced.

If the expectation that 'user name' be unique is valid then enforce it in the store i.e. prevent anyone from writing two records with the same first name. Then your test will work *as is*.

If the expectation that 'user name' be unique is not valid then your repository method should be something like ...

```
List<User> findUsersByName(String name)
```

... in which case your test might look like this:

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findUsersByName(FIRSTNAME1);
Assert.assertEquals(2, users.size());
for (User user : users) {
    Assert.assertEquals(FIRSTNAME1, user.getName()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would settle for your first paragraph but your remaining answer was more than helpful!